# Jquery append() not working

Tags: jquery

```
  $("#documentProperties").clone()
     .prop('id', 'documentProperties' + id)
     .append('<div class="col-xs-12"><input class="submit" id="dltBtn_' + id + '" type="button" value="Delete" style="margin-right: 15px;"></div>')
     .insertAfter("#doctype_" + id)
     .wrap("<div class='col-xs-12' style='margin-top: 20px;'></div>");
```

is there any error in this code? append is not appending the html in it

Comment: check the console if you are getting any error. and let us know too

Comment: what is the `id` variable being passed??

Comment: Need some more code: what does `ìd`refers to?

Comment: Also.. what does `#doctype_" + id` element refers here?

Comment: `.prop()` is for properties while `id` is an attribute

Answer (score 0):

I belive you want to insert a Id on the clone, so change `prop` to `attr`

```
 $("#documentProperties").clone()
     .attr('id', 'documentProperties' + id)
     .append('<div class="col-xs-12"><input class="submit" id="dltBtn_' + id + '" type="button" value="Delete" style="margin-right: 15px;"></div>')
     .insertAfter("#doctype_" + id)
     .wrap("<div class='col-xs-12' style='margin-top: 20px;'></div>");
```

something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bnvmczbx/